# react-native run-ios build is extremely slow

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I ran the react-native run-ios command to build my react-native app and it doesn't seem to be building(waited 20 mins). I have not encountered this issue on the same project in the past and am stumped. Previously, I had run the same app on the same laptop and it built just fine. I am currently using an updated react-native 0.61.2 on a Macbook Air 2013, could that have something to do with the issue? Note, there is no error message, the app just doesn't finish building. Picture is attached below of what I see before quitting.

Restarting my laptop didn't work.[image]

Comment: Have you tried building it through Xcode rather than the command line?

Comment: Please clean Build folder in ios folder then run commands npm start --reset-cache  and react-native run-ios

Comment: Did you happen to change the `jsCodeLocation` in the appdelegate.m ?. That should point to the entry file ?

Comment: After building from Xcode I found the following error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). Looked around for others who had this issue and it seems like it's an Xcode 10 problem? Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I too experiencing the same original issue reported, this happens even for freshly created apps, did you find any solution?

Comment: Try opening the workspace file in xcode and building from there. I haven't found a way to get the react-native run-ios command to work though.

Comment: @ParthPatel Did you try selecting `Legacy Build system` in xcode?

Comment: this is not an issue. it is due to react native. I have bought a new Mac a still it is slow.

Comment: On XCode it is still slow enough to get you desperate as well. I always ask myself if I am missing something. Why it has to build the entire application just to run it again? Why it loses connection with the metro server if I try to re-start the app in the device without going through all the build phase? This is far from hot reload, it doesn't work even if I don't make any change

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening your `/ios/*.xcworkspace` in xcode and run the project through a simulator there. You'll see the progress plus more details in case of any errors.

[image: iOS Build Process Example].